# Interfacing cassandra with JDBC getting odd hex

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, command-line-interface, cql

Im inserting data with hector and getting it back with JDBC.

The data makes no sence apart from the indexed column, im aware that this is because cassandra stores data as bytes and then converts it when its read (client converts it)

Does anyone know how to do this in JDBC for cassandra ?.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
    {
        Connection con = null;
        String _KS = "StringMsg";
        String _CFDef = "Tweets";

        try 
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/" + _KS);

            String query = "SELECT username, email, msg, id FROM " + _CFDef + " WHERE 'username'='LTodorov'";

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            System.out.println("hi");
            int i=0;
            while (result.next())
            {
                System.out.println(result.getString("id"));
                System.out.println(result.getString("username"));
                System.out.println(result.getString("msg"));
                System.out.println(result.getString("email"));
                System.out.print("count:" + i + "\n\n");i++;
            }
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (con != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    con.close();
                } 
                catch (SQLException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                con = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Results:

```
hi
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=237 lim=258 cap=798]
LTodorov
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=184 lim=209 cap=798]
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=144 lim=155 cap=798]
count:0
```

Cli Result:

```
GET Tweets Where username=LTodorov;
-------------------
RowKey: LTodorov1330045080096
=> (column=email, value=6c5f6c74404162762e6267, timestamp=1330045080214000)
=> (column=id, value=4c546f646f726f7631333330303435303830303936, timestamp=13300
45080098000)
=> (column=msg, value=54686973206973206d616b696e67206d652073616466616365, timest
amp=1330045080210000)
=> (column=username, value=LTodorov, timestamp=1330045080217000)
```

Cli Result with "assume Tweets validator as utf8";

```
RowKey: LTodorov1330045080096
=> (column=email, value=l_ld@Abv.bg, timestamp=1330045080214000)
=> (column=id, value=LTodorov1330045080096, timestamp=1330045080098000)
=> (column=msg, value=This is making me sadface, timestamp=1330045080210000)
=> (column=username, value=LTodorov, timestamp=1330045080217000)
```

Column Family Definition:

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY Tweets
WITH comparator = UTF8Type
AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
AND column_metadata = [
{column_name: id, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: email, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: msg, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: user, validation_class: UTF8Type}
```

Any cassandra gurus got any pointers? I'm getting the data back but should it be converted inside java, or should the JDBC api do the work or is it a cassandra thing ? (i think this cant be solved by cassandra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it in your java class. The result set return a few data types, look into method [getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29). You can reconstructed the byte value to [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29). For example

```
String string_username = new String(result.getBytes("username"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(string_username);
```

Comment: You mean error handling? There are many ways I can think of, for example, log it as error in your logging, whichever class that call this class method and if that got this error, they have to do other necessary changes or probably have a small try-catch block around that two statement above and try decode using other character set or call other methods from result. But I think you have good practice, that is, rather than leave to error handling, you have prevention by defining the column metadata in the first place. That is good! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the JDBC driver to me. If a column is UTF8Type in the CLI (i.e. text/varchar type in CQL) then you should be able to just use ResultSet.getString.

You can report JDBC bugs to http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/issues/list